# Subview not going below other view Swift

Tags: swift, view, popup, subview

I have a few views that are sort of like popups and when they appear a black view should appear beneath them. I use this on many other popups, however it is not working in this one specific case. I do not know why this is happening. Also, it may have to do with something that the buttons and message view are all embedded in the compliment view. Could that affect my result?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var menu: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inboxCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var complimentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inboxBackground: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var reportButton: UIButton!

@objc func complimentOutsideClicked() {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    self.complimentView.isHidden = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {self.blackview2.alpha = 0})
}

let blackview2 = UIView()

@objc func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let indexPath = self.inboxCollection?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.inboxCollection)) {
        //let cell = self.inboxCollection?.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        print("\(compliments[indexPath.row])")

        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

        self.name.text = "\(compliments[indexPath.row].sender.first_name) \(compliments[indexPath.row].sender.last_name)"

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let localDate = UTCToLocal(date: compliments[indexPath.row].created_at)
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: localDate)
        let newDate = getPastTime(for: date!)

        self.time.text = "\(newDate)"

        self.message.text = "\(compliments[indexPath.row].content)"

        if compliments[indexPath.row].is_liked == false {
            self.likeButton.isEnabled = true
            self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeButton"), for: .normal)
            self.reportButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "reportButton"), for: .normal)
            self.inboxBackground.image = UIImage(named: "inboxBackground")
        } else {
            self.likeButton.isEnabled = false
            self.likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeButtonLiked"), for: .normal)
            self.reportButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "reportButtonLiked"), for: .normal)
            self.inboxBackground.image = UIImage(named: "inboxBackgroundLiked")
        }
        self.complimentView.isHidden = false
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            blackview2.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
            window.addSubview(blackview2)
            blackview2.frame = window.frame
            blackview2.alpha = 0
            blackview2.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(complimentOutsideClicked)))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {self.blackview2.alpha = 1})
        }

        view.insertSubview(blackview2, belowSubview: messageView)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     view.insertSubview(blackview2, belowSubview: likeButton)
        view.insertSubview(blackview2, belowSubview: reportButton)
    } else {
        print("collection view was tapped")
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the blackview2 as a sub view of the keyWindow (if there is one) and then inserting it as a sub view of the view and then again and then yet again?  Only the last insertion is actually needed assuming that is where you want the view.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I am a little confused. Can you post as an answer so I can see what you mean to do

Comment: I'm not actually proposing a final answer just pointing out you are doing a load of redundant stuff.  You add the blackview2 to the keywindow.  Then you insert it in view below messageView which removes it from the keyWindow.  Then you insert it in view below likeButton which removes it and reinserts it and then do that again.  Just add/insert it once where you require it.  If you want to move it to the back of that view then you can use `view.send(toBack:)`.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth ok i will try. I appreciate your help!